# How to zoom image in flutter with CachedNetworkImage widget

Tags: flutter

can you suggest a way to zoom an image inside a `CachedNetworkImage`?

Here is my code

```
CachedNetworkImage(
        imageUrl: "http://via.placeholder.com/350x150",
        placeholder: (context, url) => CircularProgressIndicator(),
        errorWidget: (context, url, error) => Icon(Icons.error),
     ),
```

I tried to wrap CachedNetworkImage in a photo_view widget but it does not work

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Container(
    child: PhotoView(
      imageProvider: CachedNetworkImage(
        imageUrl: "http://via.placeholder.com/350x150",
        placeholder: (context, url) => CircularProgressIndicator(),
        errorWidget: (context, url, error) => Icon(Icons.error),
      )
    )
  );
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can copy paste run full code below 
Package `Cached network image` provide `CachedNetworkImageProvider` 
code snippet

```
PhotoView(
    imageProvider:
        CachedNetworkImageProvider("http://via.placeholder.com/350x150"),
  )
```

working demo

[image]

full code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:photo_view/photo_view.dart';
import 'package:cached_network_image/cached_network_image.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _counter = 0;

  void _incrementCounter() {
    setState(() {
      _counter++;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Expanded(flex: 1, child: PhotoViewTest()),
            Text(
              'You have pushed the button this many times:',
            ),
            Text(
              '$_counter',
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _incrementCounter,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class PhotoViewTest extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _PhotoViewTestState createState() => _PhotoViewTestState();
}

class _PhotoViewTestState extends State<PhotoViewTest> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: PhotoView(
        imageProvider:
            CachedNetworkImageProvider("http://via.placeholder.com/350x150"),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: is there a simple way to still include a placeholder and an errorWidget as per CachedNetworkImage? CachedNetworkImageProvider only accept the url

Comment: I have checked source code. CachedNetworkImageProvider only accept the url currently.

Answer (score 8):

You can wrap Photo view inside  Cached Network image like this code, so you can use advantages of both cached network image and photo view

```
CachedNetworkImage(
    imageUrl: "http://via.placeholder.com/350x150",
    imageBuilder: (context, imageProvider) => PhotoView(
        imageProvider: imageProvider,
    ),
    placeholder: (context, url) =>
        CircularProgressIndicator(),
        errorWidget: (context, url, error) =>
            Icon(Icons.error),
)
```

Comment: While it’s acceptable to provide code-only answers, it’s often more useful for the community if you can also provide an explanation of the code and help people understand _why_ it addresses the problem. That can reduce the number of follow-up questions, and  help new developers understand the underlying concepts. Would you mind updating your question with additional detail?

Comment: for some reason the fit property with BoxFit.cover doesn't work in this scenario

Answer (score 1):

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) { 
  return Container(
     child: CachedNetworkImage(
        imageUrl: "http://via.placeholder.com/350x150",
        imageBuilder: (context, imageProvider) => PhotoView(
           imageProvider: imageProvider,
        )
     ),
  );
}
```

Comment: @yellowgray sorry